# Is it necessary/important to set a classpath in the RMI registry?

Tags: java, registry, classpath, rmi

Is it necessary or important to set a class path in the registry for RMI to work correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440619/how-do-i-set-the-classpath-that-rmiregistry-uses

Comment: well, if you are right then thank you a lot!
But nonetheless I just want to hear the others what they know ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to @Rahul's baseless assertion, it is indeed necessary to set a CLASSPATH for the RMI Registry, unless:

1. You are starting the Registry from a directory which is also the head of a package structure of .class files.
2. You are using the codebase feature, or
3. You are starting the Registry in the same JVM as your RMI remote obects, via `LocateRegistry.createRegistry().`

If you don't do one of these four things, you will get a `ServerException` wrapping a `ClassNotFoundException` when you bind your remote object(s) to the Registry.

Comment: Oh awesome!
I really don't know what to say. Thank you very much. You really helped me a lot.